# Redux, Higher order reducer for different initialStates?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'd like to reuse a reducer but with a different initialState.

Let's say for `foo-1` reducer, I'd like to give initialState `{'foo': 1}` .
And for `foo-2` reducer, I'd like to give initialState `{'foo': 2}`

How can I write such a higher order reducer?

Answer (score 2):

Use a reducer maker:

```
function makeReducer(initialState) {
  return function(state = initialState, action) {
    // reducer logic
  }
}
```

Later use likes this

```
const firstReducer = makeReducer({'foo': 1});
const secondReducer = makeReducer({'foo': 2});
```